# Get the values according to the rearranged unordered list in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to arrange values in a text field according to the order of the list items in an unordered list.
List is as following:-

```
<ul id="sort">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

I am using `sortable()` function of Jquery UI on the list mentioned above.
I need to copy the same arrangement in a textbox value:-

```
<input type="text" value="" />
```

For example - If the list is rearranged as `3,2,5,4,1`, textbox value should be `3,2,5,4,1` :-

```
<input type="text" value="3,2,5,4,1" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you already? Maybe fiddle?

Comment: You could loop through the list and append the values to the input box with $("input #idhere").val("val here")

Comment: Please add a http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

For example like this:

```
$('#sort').sortable({
    update: function(e, ui) {
        var val = $(this).children().map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get().join();
        $('#text').val(val);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wzsuH/1/

Answer (score 0):

use sortable's stop events to check the changes.. `toArray` to get the array of the `<li>` list position... and join it with `,` and append to input

here you go..

**HTML**

```
<ul id="sort">
  <li id="1">1</li>
  <li id="2">2</li>
  <li id="3">3</li>
  <li id="4">4</li>
  <li id="5">5</li>
</ul>
```

**jquery**

```
 $('#sort').sortable({
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
   var sortedVal=$(this).sortable( "toArray" );
   var inputVal=sortedVal.join(',');
    $('#inputid').val(inputVal);
  }
});
```

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/v7NLD/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#sort li" ).each(function(){
   $("#idOfYourTextField").val( $("#idOfYourTextField").val()+ $(this).text() );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yRRLJ/1/

Comment: Modify it in whatever way you want :)